# Image rotation saving Bitmap

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, exif

I am trying to upload an image to a server through a ASP.net core. My frontend sends a base64 string of an image to my server, and I want my server to resize it to 480*680 px and save it. I convert the image to a byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(newItem.Image);
```

And use this function to Resize and Save:

```
private string ResizeAndSave(byte[] bytes)
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        string newFileName = $"{guid}.jpg";

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var image = new Bitmap(ms);
            var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 640, 480);
            var destImage = new Bitmap(640, 480);
            destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
                {
                    wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                }
            };

            var saveDir = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\images";
            if (!Directory.Exists(saveDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(saveDir);
            }

            destImage.Save($"{saveDir}/{newFileName}", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        };

        return newFileName;
    }
```

If I save the ByteArray directly, everything works, and the image comes out as I want orientation wise. But since I plan on uploading directly from a phone I want to scale the images down some. So I convert it to a Bitmap and work some magic.

However when the bitmap is loaded the image is flipped 90 degrees on the side.

I thought whatever and switched the width/height of the BitMap and Rectangle functions. Which works. Except the image was on its side, so I added a:

```
destImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
```

Before the image is saved again. It works. For IPhone - But if I upload from an Android the image is completely upside down.

I take that I need to read some EXIF tags, but there doesn't seem to be any orientation exif tags on the image I am testing with (and the bitmap PropertyIdList is empty), and even without EXIF tags it shouldn't rotate the image just by making a new Bitmap - Right?

Can anyone suggest a good way to get the correct rotation as well as downscaling of the image to a manageable size?